# javafx 8 chart getyaxis.setvisible(false) and setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false) in one click

Tags: charts, javafx

I have write a simple javafx8 application, with a LineChart and a Button.
and i want to change visible property of yaxis and horizontalgridlines, when user clicks on the button, it's what i have inside the **controller** class:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    LineChart chart;
    @FXML
    private void butClick(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        chart.getYAxis().setVisible(false);
        chart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
    }
}
```

the problem is on first click, only HorizontalGridLines disappear, and on second click, yaxis disappears.
why?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that setHorizontalGridLinesVisible invokes internally requestAxisLayout on the y axis. This seems to make the y axis visible again. Your problem can be reduced to invoking

```
    lineChart.getYAxis().setVisible(false);
    lineChart.getYAxis().requestAxisLayout();
```

The y axis won't get hidden. A workaround for your problem could be to use

```
     lineChart.getYAxis().setOpacity(0);
```

instead of setVisible();

Answer (score 0):

i've found a solution:

1- listen to horizontalgridlinevisible property of chart, and **requestLayout()** on change.

2- layout property of chart, and check if newvalue is false (layout already done) then set YAxis visibility->

```
chart.needsLayoutProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if (chart.getYAxis().isVisible()!=chart.isHorizontalGridLinesVisible())
        {
            if (!newValue)
            {
                chart.getYAxis().setVisible(chart.isHorizontalGridLinesVisible());
            }
        }
    }
});
chart.horizontalGridLinesVisibleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        chart.requestLayout();
    }
});
```